# object Object error javascript on response

Tags: javascript, html, object, error-handling

I am working on a webpage where when I enter a word and press the button, it will show the meaning of the word. I am getting an `[object Object]` error instead of the meaning of the word.

Example:
Word I entered: `code`

Result through API:

```
{"Verb": ["attach a code to", "convert ordinary language into code"], "Noun": ["a set of rules or principles or laws (especially written ones", "a coding system used for transmitting messages requiring brevity or secrecy", "(computer science"]}
```

JS:

```
var links={
    'meaning': 'link here',
}
var getMeaning = function(word){
    totalLink = links.meaning + word;
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.open("GET",totalLink, false);
    r.send();
    var data;
    if (r.status===200){
        var resp= JSON.parse(r.responseText);
        data=resp;
    }
    else{
        data='Error while running AJAX';
    }
    return data;
}
var PDictionary = function(){
    this.meaning = getMeaning;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id='a' type='text'><br>
<button id='b'>Do it</button>
<p class='out'></p>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var dictionary = new PDictionary();

    function done(){
        get();
    }
    function get(){
        var word=document.getElementById('a').value;
        meaning = dictionary.meaning(word);
        document.querySelector('.out').innerHTML = meaning;
    }
    var button = document.querySelector('#b');
    button.addEventListener('click',function(){
        get();
    });
</script>
```

On my console RESPONSE tab, I am getting the meaning of the word but on the webpage, I get the error

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? Easier for us to debug..

Comment: `[object Object]` is not an error. It's the string representation of an object. See: `console.log(String({foo: 42}));`. Just the property of the object that you want to access.

Comment: because you get the object instead of result print the object with its key to get the result ,right now it shows the whole object,,like Object['noun']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually receiving an error when it returns `[object Object]`. That is just the string representation of your object. You will need to do something to pull the actual property names and values from the object itself. You could try a [for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) like the example below.

```
var x, m = '';
for (x in meaning) {
    m += x + "<br />" + meaning[x].join("<br />") + "<br /><br />";
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle to give you an idea of how you could implement it into your own code.
https://jsfiddle.net/up2jrzp6/